# Is $G = (\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x > 0\}, +)$ with $a + b \to a^b$ a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hi MathOverflow community,

I just stumbled upon the question in the title while learning for my Algebra exam. Intuitively, I would say no since:

$$
e+a = e^a = a \\
e = \sqrt[a]{a}
$$

which depends on a and is therefore not a single neutral element for all elements of the set. Is that the right argument or is there a way to argue that more elegantly?

Comment: It's not associative: $2^{(1^2)} \ne  (2^1)^2$

Comment: The law isn’t associative : $2^{2^3} = 2^8 =256$ whereas $\left(2^2\right)^3 =2^6 =64$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another argument can be that it does not hold the associativity property, because $(a^b)^c \neq a^{(b^c)}$.

Comment: Ahh yes, that's even better! Thanks